# access: LIKE conditional formatting question

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am doing conditional formatting on a report in access

i need to check if a certain string exists in a field as the condition in conditional formatting. something like this:

```
[field_name] like '%something%'
```

will this kind of condition work?

Comment: where is remou's answer? i was going to mark it correct

Comment: i guess he thought it may have been wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use asterisk with MS Access.

```
[field_name] like '*something*'
```

For a single character, you can do this

```
[field_name] like 'fieldnam?'
```

For three characters, you can do this

```
[field_name] like 'fieldna???'
```

Comment: ...unless you're running Access in its so-called "SQL 92" mode, in which case the wildcards are the same as T-SQL, i.e., % and _.

Answer (score 1):

Access uses the asterisk instead of the percent. Try

```
[field_name] like "*something*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is a condition...

so you need something like

```
SELECT * FROM Foobar WHERE
[field_name] LIKE '*something*'
```

Comment: He's using this for conditional formatting, not as part of a full query. Ignore the SELECT * FROM Foobar WHERE part.